# Oracle Timestamp value is not converting to the java datetime

Tags: java, datetime

I have a query for an Oracle database that returns a datetime column.  In the java method, the column is converted to a string.
A portion of the code looks like this:

```
ResultSet rs;
HashMap<String, String> hm=new HashMap<String, String> ();
 hm.put("SchEndDate2", rs1.getString("END_DT_TM_GMT"));
```

When I view the strings value in the debugger it looks like this: **"2019-07-04 11:00:00.0"**
I need to convert this string to the datetime format of this: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm"

I tried this SimpleDateFormat to complete this but when I convert the string to the format it returns the dateTime in Eastern Daylight Time and not GMT.
The value after going thru the conversion is this: **"Thu Jul 04 07:00:00 EDT 2019"**
This is the code that I am using to convert the string to a DateTime.

```
  EndDate=map.get("SchEndDate2");
//EndDate : **"2019-07-04 11:00:00.0"**
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date databaseDateTime = formatter.parse(EndDate);
//databaseDateTime: **"Thu Jul 04 07:00:00 EDT 2019"**
```

Why is the format incorrect and the timezone not correctly set?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead just use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Eh? It already is a `java.sql.Timestamp`. Don't convert it to String, and don't convert it back. Use `rs.getTimestamp()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the `Date` object to an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Here's an example showing your input string first converted to a `Date`, and then converting that to an `Instant`. The date contains the timezone-specific rendering, but the instant does not.

```
String input = "2019-07-04 11:00:00.0";
System.out.println("input:   " + input);

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = formatter.parse(input);
System.out.println("date:    " + date);

Instant instant = date.toInstant();
System.out.println("instant: " + instant);
```

And here's the output:

```
input:   2019-07-04 11:00:00.0
date:    Thu Jul 04 05:00:00 MDT 2019
instant: 2019-07-04T11:00:00Z
```

Comment: yep...that did it! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Two points.

1. Don’t fetch your date and time as a string from Oracle. Fetch a proper date-time object. In this case a `LocalDateTime`.
2. Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

In code:

```
    ResultSet rs = // …;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject("END_DT_TM_GMT", LocalDateTime.class);

    String databaseDateTimeAsString = dateTime.toString();

    System.out.println(databaseDateTimeAsString);
```

Example output:

> 2019-07-04T11:00

It’s not quite the output format that you asked for, but it most likely will serve your purpose. The format you asked for is ISO 8601. So is the output I have given you. In the ISO 8601 standard, including the seconds and fraction of second when they are 0 is optional. If you insist on including them, use a formatter. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    String databaseDateTimeAsString = dateTime.format(formatter);
```

> 2019-07-04T11:00:00.000

Using `rs.getObject()` for getting a `LocalDateTime` as shown requires a JDBC 4.2 compliant database driver. You probably have got that. In case you haven’t and you cannot upgrade, use:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = rs.getTimestamp("END_DT_TM_GMT").toLocalDateTime();
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)